# Random Values from a variable set of entries in a vector

Tags: vector, random

i have a problem which is the following:

i have for example 4 objects. One object is randomly selected to do a certain action. E.g. if object 1 does an action, the other 3 objects do nothing.

So, i have a vector of these objects.

vector{object1,object2, object3, object4}

In the beginning, i can easily randomly select one object with vector[random].

And here comes the problem: An object can also "die" meaning the object should not be part of the random-step anymore.

For example, if object2 dies, if want to random between 1,3,4 and let the 2 out.

Is this possible somehow? (using C++)

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried? Is there a problem with your shift key?

Answer (score 0):

I was just under the shower and thought about it.. i think i found a workaround for this. Pseudo-Code:

```
vector<figure> all_figure_types;
vector<figure> all_figure_types_alive;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    all_figure_types.push_back(generate_random_number(1,10));
}
all_figure_types_alive.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < all_figure_types.size(); i++) {

    if (all_figure_types[i].is_alive) {

        all_figure_types_alive.push_back(all_figure_types[i]);
    }
}

int start = 0;
int end = all_figure_types_alive.size();

int random_num = generate_random_number(start, end);

int object_type = all_figure_types_alive[random_num].type;
```

If there is a nicer version without resetting this helping-construct all_figure_types_alive, let me know would be nice to hear!